# Power of Two Textures in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

OpenGL 1.3 does not support [NPOT](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/NPOT_Texture) textures. All the images that I'm being supplied with do not fit this specification as I'm doing 2D and drawing sprites.

Is there any precoded workaround for this?

If not, what are the best options for coding around this? Padding with transparent pixels? Splitting into sub-textures?

Comment: Have you checked if your graphic card supports [ARB_texture_rectangle](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_rectangle.txt)? It allows NPOTS.

Comment: I read somewhere that it's not cross platform, so it's not something that I can use.

Comment: @VolatileStorm GL_ARB extensions aren't tied to a specific platform, i've used them on Windows, Linux and OS X and they work fine.

Comment: Okay, well I had a go at implimenting it. I replaced GL_TEXTURE_2D with "GL_ARB_texture_rectangle". This had the unfortunate effect of causing every rendered texture to now become the first loaded one. Do you have any idea why this would be, and how to get around it?
(I am calling glGenTextures individually for each texture:
  glGenTextures(1, &self_texture);
  glBindTexture(GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, self_texture);
)
Thanks!

(What I mean by first loaded is that it's rendering all of the textures as the same thing - the first one loaded).

Comment: @Volatile: Read [the spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_rectangle.txt).  That's not how you use `ARB_texture_rectangle`.

Comment: Fun that it compiled what I had before, then! From fiddling and googling I'd already gotten to using GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB. That is, I've now replaced all instances of GL_TEXTURE_2D with GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB. I tried reading the spec and I think that's what it means. (It's a texture target, right?). However, this produces new problems as EVERY texture is now a gradient. That is the bottom left of the texture is grey, the top right is white and it gradients in between. This does have me puzzled. Help?

Comment: Further reading of the spec has got me somewhere! I was using 0 and 1 to refer to the extremes of the texture when rendering it - however this texture target wants the actual texture extrema in pixels. So that fixed that problem! However, it seems to have broken a library I was using to draw text - which I think uses normal textures to draw letters. It still experiences the "gradient" issue I just described.

Is there any reason that using GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB would upset the use of GL_TEXTURED_2D elsewhere in code?

Comment: An addendum - I'm using the "texfont" api.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to deal with this is to resample the texture. If you roll your own, a simple bilinear filter should be sufficient to resize to the next power of two. Otherwise, there's plenty of image filtering frameworks out there.

Splitting is not recommended if you have filtering enabled.

You can use padding if you don't need texture-wrapping. The color of the pixels you use for it, however, depends on the clamp mode for the texture and the border color, if you're using that.

Comment: I am still very new to openGL, and do not know how to resample a texture, and I was struggling with the googling. Any help on that? Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation - any more information on that would be a separate question here.